# Checking pipeline status stuck

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed gitlab-runner into a container, and made it register.
I got a runner with the green light into my gitlab.private.com open but seems that the  Checking pipeline status is stuck and have no way to debug it or understand what's going on, really frustrating.

- I have a private gitlab with a domain name, called gitlab.mydomain.com
- Created a project with nodeJS application.
- Created the Dockerfile and the build works perfectly in the server.
  I want to autobuild my images and then push them to hub.docker.com where i got a pro account with private repository.

I have this .gitlab-ci.yml file, i just want to test the build on gitlab so made it simple but nothing happening.

```
image: docker:stable

    stages:
      - Build image
    
    docker build:
      stage: Build image
      script:
        - docker info
        - docker build -t private/project:1.0 .
```

I share with you my container logs for gitlab-runner, i have no idea what does this mean also.
Got it when i execute docker logs container_id

```
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml ...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Metrics server disabled
```

[image]